# Merging data from one table to another table with out any relation

Tags: sql

I have 2 sql tables( A and B) with no relation among them. I wanted to copy the data of one column of table B and merge it with the table A as a new column of able B

How do i do that.
I have tried to write this code -

```
 Insert into TableA(ColumnC) select top 10 ColumnA from TableB
```

Comment: you can't create a new column using insert.

Comment: but maybe you can create a new table (in some dbmses)

Comment: +Leo, Also how do you intend to match the tables if they have no relation between them?

Comment: Define `no relation among them`?

Comment: You need to alter the table to add a new field, then use update to insert data into the new field.

Comment: no relation means there is no common column btwn 2 table to join them.

Comment: I have already alter the able with one new field. but now i stuck at coping the data from 2nd table to 1st table

Comment: Based on that tidbit of information as jpw stated, you need to update table A with values from table B using an update statement not an insert. Again your problem is the tables don't relate, so not sure how you will update them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your interest!! It is not that complex it looks. one of the trick is to create an auxiliary Column base on row_number for both table and join both table on that column.. Phew!! finally :)